# Angular provider not using mock class in Test bench

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to write unit tests for one of my Angular components that gets data from a web service call. Everything runs fine but the Angular test bench is always using the real service call instead of the provided mock service class. I am using Angular 6 & Jasmine 3.

Here is the spec file, as you can see I am providing a mock service that returns an observable with my predefined data.

```
describe('MyComponent Service Integration', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

class MockService{
  getData(){
    return of(data); //data imported from json file
  }
}

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ MyComponent],
    imports:[HttpClientTestingModule],
    providers:[{provide : MyService, useClass: MockService}],
  })
  .compileComponents();
});

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BalanceComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create a my component with data from the service', () => {
  ngOnInit();
  expect(component.data).toBe(data);
}
```

Is there something I am missing here? When the test bench creates MyComponent it should inject my MockService into the component not MyService correct? I just can't figure this one out, any help would be great.

Here is my dead simple component that is under test.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  data : any;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.myService.getData().subscribe(
     response =>{
       this.data = response;
     },
     error =>{
       console.log("ERROR");
     });
   }
}
```